# How to add Properties.Settings.Default in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties.settings

I am not able to write "Properties.Settings.Default". It is not coming in the dropdown list. Is there any namespace that we can add?

Comment: what type of application is it ? is it console based or winform based ?

Comment: Winform based application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your project namespace to the Properties namespace. The default namespace defined in the project settings.

For instance if your project default namespace is MyApp.

```
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default
```

Comment: "Properties" is not suggested in dropdownlist.. Is there any particular namespace for it??

Comment: Look at your project settings and find the default namespace for your project. For instance if it is "MyApp" try MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default

Answer (score 1):

An additional hint on top of the above answers:

> Go to solution explorer -> Properties folder -> Settings.settings ->
>   Settings.Designer.cs file

and see which namespace is being used there. Ensure that you are using this namespace in your code file as others have suggested

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the same namespace and try to access the properties like this :

```
namespace.Properties.Settings.Default
```

or if you are on different namespace don't forget to use

```
using namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you setup your environment in the settings under properties of the app. You want to reference it to the project like this:

using App.Properties.Settings

Then in the code you write you can use as example:

userName.Settings.Default

In this case userName is set within the settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your Setting in your project
   go to Project => property   =>  go to setting
2. Set your element (string,int, ecc...)
3. Save from program all values

Properties.Settings.Default.User = txtUser.Text;                Properties.Settings.Default.Password = txtPass.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

if you use Windows 10, this is the directory of setting Values:
C:\Users\AppData\Local<ProjectName.exe_Url_somedata>\1.0.0.0<filename.config>